# Unable to start VM from php

Tags: virtual-machine, php, linux-kvm, qemu, php5

From a php page I am trying to start Virtual Machine using virsh tool on KVM hypervisor but I am getting this error.

```
error: Failed to connect socket to '@/var/www/.libvirt/libvirt-sock': Connection refused
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor.
```

Please suggest some work around.
Is it possible doing this without giving www-data user, root privilege?

Thanks

Comment: I found the answer. Instead of using php functions like exec() or shell_exec() use libvirt-php API http://libvirt.org/php/api-reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Way**

Php code

`<?php
    $output=shell_exec("virsh -c qemu:///system start vmname 2>&1");
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>`

Beside that run this command in terminal in Ubuntu 12.04 , can do same for other flavors.

`sudo chown www-data /var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock`

Additionally you can use

`sudo visudo
www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/virsh`

**Second Way**

Use `libvirt-php API` to start the VM. To start VM use `libvirt_domain_create` function. See this for more information http://libvirt.org/php/api-reference.html#libvirt_domain_create